# Read in a Json File in powershell, and get values out of it

Tags: json, powershell

I try to extract data from a json file i imported into powershell, the import part works fine for me, i am also able to see my output, but i want to get only the date of the Categorie "v", i have no idea how to figure it out. i tried something like:

```
$vPSObject.v.getValue(0)
```

but this dont work for me.

by code looks like:

```
$file= Get-Content "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\test.json"   

#write-host $file

$file= $file -split '"d":'


$file2=$file 

$file=$file2 | ConvertFrom-Json



$vPSObject= $file2 | ConvertFrom-Json 



$vPSObject.v

$vPSObject.n
```

my output looks like:

```
t n        v                                                                                                                                                                                
- -        -                                                                                                                                                                                
d 000064s2 {10.05.2021, , , testfile (user)}                                                                                                           
d 00006deCE {06.11.2020, , , testfile2}                                                                                                              
d 00006dasdCA {06.11.2020, , , testfile3 (user2)}
```

my output should look like:

```
000064s2 10.05.2021
00006deCE 06.11.2020                                                                                                            
00006dasdCA 06.11.2020
```

so i could store it into a array to work with it later.

part of my json file:

```
{
      "t": "d",
      "n": "000061B6",
      "v": [
        "20.07.2016",
        "",
        "",
        "test"
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `json` looks like this when converted to `object[]`:

```
t n           v                     
- -           -                     
d 000061B6    {10.05.2021, , , test}
d 00006deCE   {06.11.2020, , , test}
d 00006dasdCA {06.11.2020, , , test}
```

You can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/selecting-parts-of-objects--select-object-?view=powershell-7.1) to get the result you want (this is assuming that the **Date** on the `v` property is always the **position 0 of the array**):

```
$json | Select-Object n, @{n='v';e={$_.v[0]}}
```

Output:

```
n           v         
-           -         
000061B6    10.05.2021
00006deCE   06.11.2020
00006dasdCA 06.11.2020
```

After converting this output to `json`:

```
[
    {
        "n":  "000061B6",
        "v":  "10.05.2021"
    },
    {
        "n":  "00006deCE",
        "v":  "06.11.2020"
    },
    {
        "n":  "00006dasdCA",
        "v":  "06.11.2020"
    }
]
```

---

```
$newJson = $json | Select-Object n, @{n='v';e={$_.v[0]}}

PS /> $newJson.n
000061B6
00006deCE
00006dasdCA

PS /> $newJson.v
10.05.2021
06.11.2020
06.11.2020

PS /> $newJson.v[0]
10.05.2021
```

Comment: is there i way i can store the values in seperate variables, by editing this code line ` $json | Select-Object n, @{n='v';e={$_.v[0]}` ? @Santiago Squarzon

Comment: @du7ri yeah, of course, see my last edit.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you really want to create an array of *strings* each of which is composed of property values joined with a space, use the following:

```
(ConvertFrom-Json (Get-Content -Raw C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive\Desktop\test.json)) | 
  ForEach-Object { '{0} {1}' -f $_.n, $_.v[0] }
```

You can prepend `[array] $strings =`  to the command above in order to collect all resulting strings.

If, by contrast, you want to create *objects* with the properties of interest, see [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68179196/45375).